# How do I create generalized binary tarballs for SageMath?

Tags: binary, compatibility

I would like to create a generalized binary tarball (i.e., a tar-compressed archive that contains an executable shell script for a wide range of different Linux distributions. It must be first extracted in order for one to be able to run this executable script) for [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/). I think this should be possible as generalized binary tarballs are available for the mathematics software, [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org/download/5.5.2). A similar question I asked may be found on [Ask SageMath](http://ask.sagemath.org/question/28795/why-are-the-binary-tarballs-for-debianubuntu-the-only-ones-provided-officially-for-sagemath/).

Comment: download from scilab are compressed tarball, but not self extractable. those are created with `tar cvzf foo.tar.gz files files ...`

Comment: Yep, I know they are not self-extractable. Your comment only prompts me to edit my question to make it include the info therein, doesn't really get me closer to the answer, though.

Comment: so the question boils down to: "I want to create a portable shell across as many linux distribtion as possible" ? thee have undergo a very long quest.

Comment: Starting point is likely here -> http://www.megastep.org/makeself/